# style div next to and on top of each others

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, components, styling

so i have divs created in react basically they are components and i want to style them using bootstrap like this:

```
div div div

div     div

div     div
```

so basically there are 5components,the top 3 should be small and stack next to each others with small margin. the middle two are bigger and they are under the right and left divs and the bottom ones the same as the middle divs.

i have tried doing like col-6 for the middle and col-4 for the top ones but they were all over the place and messy.

this is what i tried without using css just bootstrap:

```
<div className="container">
          <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-4">
          <Card />

          <ActualLineChart data={systolic}/>

          <ActualLineChart data={Diastolic}/>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-6">
              <div>
          <ActualBarChart data={systolicAndDiastolicAndPulseAverageNew}/>
          </div>
          <ActualScatterChart data={systolicAndDiastolicAndPulseAverageNew}/>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-6">
          <DistributionChart/>

          <DistributionChart />
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

how can i do this behavior?

Comment: are you using `react-bootstrap`?

Comment: @FareedKhan yes

Comment: Can i see how are you using `col` and `row` component in your  `app.js`?

Comment: Your use of col-4 and col-6 would be the right approach, so there might be a missing row.   The diagram is helpful to understand what you want, but if share your code folks will be able to help pinpoint the problem better.

Comment: @FareedKhan i edited the code here and provided what i did

Comment: @jme11 i edited the code this is what i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that if you are using `react-bootstrap` you probably have already `installed` it and included react component in your `app.js` file using this

```
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'React-Bootstrap';
```

Then you can simply use this for your desired output.

```
<Container>

  <Row>
    <Col xs="4">
     component 1
    </Col>
    <Col xs="4">
     component 2
    </Col>
    <Col xs="4">
     component 3
    </Col>
  </Row>

  <Row className="justify-content-between">
    <Col xs="4">
     component 4
    </Col>
    <Col xs="4">
     component 5
    </Col>
  </Row>

  <Row className="justify-content-between">
    <Col xs="4">
     component 6
    </Col>
    <Col xs="4">
     component 7
    </Col>
  </Row>

</Container>
```

Output will be look like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you so so much for your help it looks great!! just one more question if i want the middle components( ex component 4 and 5 ) to touch, should i just remove justify-content-between?

Comment: Yes if you remove `justify-content-between` for `row` contain `component 4` and `component 5` then it will look like this: https://ibb.co/1TWfZnd  and if you use `jusitfy-content-center` it will look like this https://ibb.co/Y7W99XQ